# How can I get back into my main processing thread?

Tags: ios, multithreading, ios6, nsurlconnection, objective-c-blocks

I have an app that I'm accessing a remote website with `NSURLConnection` to run some code and then save out some XML files.  I am  then accessing those XML Files and parsing through them for information.  The process works fine except that my User Interface isn't getting updated properly.  I want to keep the user updated through my `UILabel`.  I'm trying to update the text by using `setBottomBarToUpdating:`.  It works the first time when I set it to "Processing Please Wait..."; however, in the `connectionDidFinishLoading:` it doesn't update. I'm thinking my NSURLConnection is running on a separate thread and my attempt with the `dispatch_get_main_queue` to update on the main thread isn't working. How can I alter my code to resolve this? Thanks! [If I need to include more information/code just let me know!]

**myFile.m**

```
NSLog(@"Refreshing...");

dispatch_sync( dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
     [self getResponse:@"http://mylocation/path/to/file.aspx"];
});

[self setBottomBarToUpdating:@"Processing Please Wait..."];

queue = dispatch_queue_create("updateQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
```

**connectionDidFinishLoading:**

```
if ([response rangeOfString:@"Complete"].location == NSNotFound]) {
  // failed
} else {
  //success
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^ {
       [self setBottomBarToUpdating:@"Updating Contacts..."];
  });

  [self updateFromXMLFile:@"http://thislocation.com/path/to/file.xml"];

  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^ {
       [self setBottomBarToUpdating:@"Updating Emails..."];
  });

  [self updateFromXMLFile:@"http://thislocation.com/path/to/file2.xml"];  

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my connectionDidFinishLoading: I would try something like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0),^ {
    if ([response rangeOfString:@"Complete"].location == NSNotFound]) {
      // failed
    } else {
      //success
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^ {
           [self setBottomBarToUpdating:@"Updating Contacts..."];
      });

      [self updateFromXMLFile:@"http://thislocation.com/path/to/file.xml"];

      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^ {
           [self setBottomBarToUpdating:@"Updating Emails..."];
      });

      [self updateFromXMLFile:@"http://thislocation.com/path/to/file2.xml"];  
    }
});
```

Then all that file access is happening in a background queue so the main queue is not locked up. The main queue will also complete this call to connectionDidFinishLoading much more quickly, since you're throwing all the hard work onto the default queue instead, which should leave it (and the main thread) ready to accept your enqueuing of the updates to the UI which will be done by the default queue as it processes the block you just enqueued to it.

The queue handover becomes

- main thread callback to connectionDidFinishLoad:
- rapid handoff to default global queue releasing main thread
- eventual hand off to main queue for setBottomBarToUpdating: calls
- performing main queue blocks on main thread to properly update UI
- eventual completion of blocks on main queue
- eventual completion of blocks on default queue

You've increased concurrency (good where you've good multi-core devices) and you've taken the burden of I/O off the main thread (never a good place for it) and instead got it focused on user interface work (the right place for it).

Ideally you woud run the NSURLConnection run loop off the main thread too, but this will might be enough for you to get going.

Answer (score 0):

You could also give `performSelectorOnMainThread` try like so:

```
if ([response rangeOfString:@"Complete"].location == NSNotFound]) {
                // failed
            } else {
                //success
                [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setBottomBarToUpdating) withObject:@"Updating Contacts..." waitUntilDone:false];

                [self updateFromXMLFile:@"http://thislocation.com/path/to/file.xml"];

                [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setBottomBarToUpdating) withObject:@"Updating Emails..." waitUntilDone:false];


                [self updateFromXMLFile:@"http://thislocation.com/path/to/file2.xml"];  

            }
```

Comment: If I do it that way do i even need the `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{});` ?

Comment: opps i forgot to take that off, no you wouldnt need `dispatch_get_main_queue`

Comment: Yeah, don't mix performSelectorOnMainThread: and dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^ {.

Comment: I attempted this but looks like it's already running on the main thread and doesn't do anything differently. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Which run loop are you running the NSURLConnection in? If it's the main loop, you're queueing up the setBottomBarToUpdating: calls behind the work you're already doing, hence the probable reason why you're not seeing the UI update.

Comment: I suspect that's the problem then. Your connectionDidFinishLoading: is already being executed by the main thread. You can check this by using [NSThread isMainThread]. So, your thread is tired up with the networking. If so, I would throw the whole handler for connectionDidFinishLoading: onto a background queue and enqueue your UI updates from that queue. Ideally you would run your connections on another run loop, but this would be a quick way to get the main thread freed up.

Comment: I'm kinda new to all this I think, I tried the `[NSThread isMainThread]` and it does confirm its already in the main thread.  Could you perhaps explain with some code example what your solution for the problem would be? Thanks